# i am getting [0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0m in jenkins console on building sbt jenkins pipeline project

Tags: jenkins, sbt

i have an sbt project in jenkins, created the project as jenkins pipeline project, i have installed sbt in jenkins, i have checked the auto install checkbox and select the version number 1.2.8

here is my jenkins file

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Reload') {
            steps {
                echo "Reloading..."
                //sh "sbt reload"
                 sh "${tool name: 'sbt1.2.8', type: 'org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder$SbtInstallation'}/bin/sbt compile"
            }
        }
}
}

and here is sbt settings in jenkins
```

[image]

here is jenkins console logs

```
+ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.SbtPluginBuilder_SbtInstallation/sbt1.2.8/bin/sbt compile
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0mLoading settings for project interpret-backend-project-jenkinsfile-build from plugins.sbt ...[0m
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0mLoading project definition from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/interpret-backend-project-jenkinsfile/project[0m
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0mLoading settings for project interpret-backend-project-jenkinsfile from build.sbt ...[0m
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0mSet current project to interpret (in build file:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/interpret-backend-project-jenkinsfile/)[0m
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0mExecuting in batch mode. For better performance use sbt's shell[0m
[0m[[0m[32msuccess[0m] [0m[0mTotal time: 4 s, completed Nov 25, 2020, 4:53:05 PM[0m
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
[Checks API] No suitable checks publisher found.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

```
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0m why is this displaying how can i fix this ?
```

Answer (score 3):

These are ANSI color codes. You can either embrace them to have colorful logs or disable them.

To enable colors in Jenkins you can modify your pipeline definition:

```
pipeline {
    ...
    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }
    ...
}
```

This is a reference to the [AnsiColor](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ansicolor/) plugin.

If you can't use this plugin and want to disable colors in sbt logs, you can do that by modifying `sbt.color` option. For example, by launching sbt with `-Dsbt.color=false` (I see that you can add this to in the UI) or by adding it to the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable:

```
pipeline{
    ...
    environment {
        SBT_OPTS = "${SBT_OPTS} -Dsbt.color=false"
    }
    ...
}
```

Check out [sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Command+Line+Options) and take a look at the `sbt.ci` option as well, it should be automatically set on Jenkins.